# Why is the variable not undefined?

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner to JavaScript, and was wondering why the following code snippet alerts "Successful" even though the definition for "message" has not been provided for the function to use.

```js
var message;

function alertMessage() {
   alert(message);
}

message = "Successful";

alertMessage();
```

The following code returns undefined, so I'm assuming the function has something to do with it?

```js
var message;

alert(message);

message = "Successful";
```

Comment: By the time the function is called, you have defined the variable.

Comment: That aside, the function is hoisted anyway so it really doesn't matter. You could put `function alertMessage() {...}` *after* the call to `alertMessage()` and it'll work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a look at what this code does line by line.

```
var message; // 1

function alertMessage() { // 2
   alert(message);
}

message = "Successful"; // 3

alertMessage(); // 4
```

1: Declares a variable named `message`.

2: Declares a function named `alertMessage` that uses the variable. Note that this function is *not* executed at this point yet. It's only *declared*.

3: Sets the value of the variable `message` to `"Successful"`.

4: Calls the function. Now the function is executed. Note that the variable `message` has been set to `"Successful"` in the previous step, so at the point when the function is executed, it has that value - and that's why you see it.

Now, let's look at the second code snippet.

```
var message; // 1

alert(message); // 2

message = "Successful"; // 3
```

What's happening here:

1: Declare a variable named `message`. It has not been set to a value yet, so it's `undefined` at this point.

2: Call the `alert` function with the variable `message`. This will display `undefined` because `message` is `undefined` at this point.

3: Set the variable `message` to the value `"Successful"`. This won't help the call to `alert` in step 2 - that's already done by the time you get here.

**Important to remember**: A program is a list of commands, that is executed from the top to the bottom. If you want to know what a program does, read it line by line, starting at the top. What's in the lines happens one after the other. Not all at once, and not in a different order.

A function is not executed when it's declared. It's executed when it's called.

Answer (score 3):

In first case steps are the following:

1. message is declared but undefined.
2. function is declared but not executed.
3. to variable message there is assigned value
4. function is executed when message has value

In second case

1. message is declared but undefined
2. function (alert) is executed, and you see undefined
3. then to message you assign value

Answer (score 2):

The function is a blueprint if you think about it.
It isnt used until you "call" it.

In the first example. You first defined message and then you "called" the function, it works like intended.

In the second example message has no value -> it's empty, that is why it is "undefined".
If you set it for example message = "bla bla bla", it wouldn't be undefined.

Is this explanation ok?

Comment: I'm still confused because I thought that JavaScript worked in order. In other words, if you declare a variable with no value, and the function which comes after it uses that variable, it cannot 'see' that the variable has a value.

I assume functions are hoisted to the top, as Niet said?

Comment: No, the function doesn't need to 'see' anything until it is used. Is that ok? You don't say "I'm ok" when nobody asked you "Are you ok?", that is same in functions, they don't activate until you call them, they don't read or use variable names until they need to

Comment: Jesper's answer made sense. The "blueprint" for the function includes a variable, and the variable is then changed after the function declaration, which the function still points to.

Answer (score 1):

In the second example you are calling alert on the message before it is set to successful.

Order of execution

Declare message and set it to undefined

Call alert on message which displays undefined

Set message = successful

The first example

Declare message and set it to undefined

Declare a function that calls the alert message when executed

Note this does nothing until it's called

Set message to successful

Call the function above

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass it by setting message = "error"